# Static block not showing anchor tags

Tags: magento-1.7, static-block, edit

I'm working on Magento CE verison  1.7.0.2 and `found a very strange bug. In a static block there are some static images linked,` but i c`an't see any anchor tag`.

Instead, `using phpmyadmin`, i can `see those and  was able to change it`!
Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: show your code.. please

Comment: sorry, I can't show it anymore because, after changing the content through phpmyadmin, they have been now restored.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the WYSIWYG editor and try again. It has some known issues and this might be the case.

Open admin section, go to System -> Configuration -> Content Management.

In the field "Enable WYSIWYG Editor" you will see options for WYSIWYG editor. Select Disabled Completely and see it your issue still reproduces.